# Reclassify points within a bounding box with PDAL

Tags: classification, las, point-cloud, pdal, laz

I have a list of 3D bounding boxes manually drawn around noise points and I want to reclassify them as noise. One option would be to simply drop them but, in this particular case, I would want to have them labeled as noise.

To do this, I came up with the following PDAL pipeline:

```
[
    {
        "filename": str(file),
        "tag": "source",
    },
    {"type": "filters.crop", "bounds": pdal_boxes},
    {"type": "filters.assign", "value": "Classification = 7", "tag": "noise"},
    {
        "type": "filters.crop",
        "bounds": pdal_boxes,
        "outside": True,
        "tag": "out_of_the_box",
        "inputs": ["source"],
    },
    {"type": "filters.merge", "inputs": ["out_of_the_box", "noise"]},
    {"type": "writers.las", "filename": str(output), "forward": "all"},
]
```

This looks a bit silly... My idea was to crop the region, classify it as noise and merge it back with the original file with the noise dropped.

I am sorry if this question is silly but I just couldn't find any example of how to do this operation in the documentation.

**OBS:** The bounding boxes are 3D so I can't easily use "filter.overlay"